# Calculating student attendance using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following table schemas, how would you figure out the overall attendance rate for each grade on 2018-03-12?

Table 1: student_attendance_log

| column name | Data Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| date | string | date of log per student_id, format is 'yyyy-mm-dd' |
| student_id | integer | id of the student |
| attendance_status | string | Possible values are ['present', 'tardy', 'absent'] |

Table 2: student_demographic

| column name | Data Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| student_id | integer | id of the student |
| grade_level | integer | will be a value between 0-12, which corresponds |
| date_of_birth | string | Student birth date, format is 'yyyy-mm-dd' |

is my solution below correct?

```
select grade_level,
       sum(if(attendence_status = 'present', 1,0))/count(AD.student_id) as overall_attendance_rate
from student_demographic SD
  join student_attendance_log SL
    on SD.student_id = SL.student_id
   and date='2018-03-12'
group by 1
```

Comment: No it's not correct, because your solution doesn't even run. There is no `if()` function in SQL (or Postgres)

Comment: Postgres does have a CASE statement: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-case

Comment: I don't understand the `group by` - how does it partition the results if it is always `1`?  You would want `group by grade_level` wouldn't you?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah  In this case it is not grouping by the value 1, but by the column position 1 (first column in list). So it is grouping by grade_level.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, i wasn't aware postgres doest support IF. I will change it to case statement.


select grade_level,
sum(case when attendence_status = 'present' then 1 else 0 end)/count(AD.student_id) as overall_attendance_rate    
from student_demographic SD
  join student_attendance_log SL
    on SD.student_id = SL.student_id
   and date='2018-03-12'
group by 1

Comment: @JerryJeremiah i am grouping on column 1 i.e., grouping by grade_level.